# Use recursion to count the length of a string

Tags: java, string, recursion

I am studying recursion in class at this time and for an assignment we are to count the length of a string using recursion without the use of .getLength or anything like that. This is what I've tried but so far I am getting an error on line 20 and am confused.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


 public class StringCounter {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a String: ");
    String s = kb.nextLine();
    System.out.println("The length of your string is: " + stringLength(s));
}

public static int stringLength(String s) {
    if (s.equals(""))
        return 0;
    else
        return stringLength(s.substring(0)) + 1;
}

}
```

Comment: What sort of error?  And which line is 20?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at java.lang.String.equals(Unknown Source)
 at StringCounter.stringLength(StringCounter.java:18)
 at StringCounter.stringLength(StringCounter.java:21)
 18 is the if statement and 21 is the else

Comment: `s.substring(0)` returns `s`... so you're getting a `StackOverflow` error because you put an infinite number of calls to `stringLength` on the stack because you keep calling it with the same thing over and over and `s.equals("")` never returns `true`.

Comment: Your recursive function is answering itself more times than expected, and running out of memory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are doing infinite recursion because you're passing the same string.  Change to this:

```
return stringLength(s.substring(1)) + 1;
                            //  ^
```

Comment: What does this method call return for a string with only 1 character (where index 1 is out of bounds)?

Comment: @nhgrif The official documentation says *throws IndexOutOfBoundsException if beginIndex is negative or larger than the length of this String object*.  You are allowed to pass an index equal to the length of the string, and you would expect an empty string to be returned.

Comment: Okay.  Thanks.  I was going to post an answer, but wasn't familiar with the behavior in this scenario (and figured by the time I looked it up, there'd be an answer).

Answer (score 2):

You are starting with index 0 for the substring call in the recursive call. I guess you meant to use index 1. It works when you change to `s.substring(1)`

Answer (score 1):

Probably you're getting a memory or stack overflow (heh) error; try

```
return stringLength(s.substring(1)) + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **stringLength(s.substring(1)) + 1;**.

If you use s.substring(0), the string value is not changed. That is why the code is in infinite recursion and as a result throws out an error java.lang.StackOverflowError.